# htacces - Redirect old url to new

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect old url to new with additional parameter

How can I prevent creating many youtube parameter ?

**OLD**: http://example.com/lady-gaga-monster

**NEW**: http://example.com/lady-gaga-monster-youtube

**Currently htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-youtube?$ index.php?search=$1&source=youtube [L]
```

I add this line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com//$1-youtube [R=301,L]
```

And the result on browser
http://example.com/lady-gaga-monster-youtube-youtube-youtube-youtube-youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an endless loop. You need to add a RewriteCOnd so that the rule gets only applied if the requested URL does not end in "-youtube":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# external rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-youtube$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1-youtube [R=301,L]
# internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)-youtube$ index.php?search=$1&source=youtube [L]
```

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: hi @arkascha, Thank you very for you answer but still not work :)

Comment: And "still not work" means what _exactly_? What happens? Did you _really_ clear your browsers cache? What do you see in your http servers error log file?

Comment: Good to hear. Please be fair and share your customization so that others can benefit from it ;-)

Comment: Ok, I accepted that edit, it would only be visible to you yourself otherwise as _proposed_ edit. I do not understand what difference that modification should make, though...

Comment: before I added 3 lines of code, everytime I visit the site will direct to http://example.com/-youtube

Comment: I cannot see any connection between what you observe and those lines, sorry. There has to be some unexpected thing interfering here. Could it be that you have auto negotiation enabled? Have a try adding `Options -MultiViews` and retry.

Comment: everything is OK, if the url contain keywords.
example.com/keyword-keyword-keyword
automatically redirect to example.com/keyword-keyword-keyword-youtube as I want.

But problems arise when I visited the main page example.com will go to example/-youtube, thats why the codes is need because before I didn't use

Comment: So _that_ is the issue you referred to initially with "but still not work"? _Why didn't you say so?_ Obviously every assumed that no rewriting was performed or something. Do you understand now how important it is to answer in a precise manner? To clearly name _what exactly_ the actual issue is instead of just claiming "does not work"?

Comment: Anyway, glad to hear that you solved your initial task! Have fun!